# Dynamic ViewPager open new activity from Viewpager in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-settings

I have a dynamic Viewpager and I add pages with title.
In Viewpager I have and Setting button that sends you in
new Activity but when I go back in ViewPager all my views which
I have added have deleted.
What should I do to not lose views??

Comment: Can you show your code? 

And try load your post in onCreate()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.